# How to do end to end testing for an Ext JS application

Tags: javascript, testing, extjs

I just started using Ext JS to build a relatively complex web application for my company, involving over 200 screens. So we definitely need automated e2e testing.

I am using Jasmine to do unit testing of my controllers and models. However, I want to be able to simulate user navigating through the web app. Is there any good testing framework to do this sort of automated testing?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium is the de-facto UI integration testing framework and it has very comprehensive tooling. Watir gets a lot of love in Ruby circles and I've heard a few things about Sahi. I only have personal experience with Selenium, but it seems to stand out much more than the others. See the link below.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606550/watir-vs-selenium-vs-sahi